# How do I resolve package conflicts on Fedora 37?

Tags: fedora, upgrade

I'm running Fedora 37, and for the past couple of weeks, I've noticed that it skips some packages when I type `sudo dnf upgrade` saying there are conflicts between them. The packages are `ffmpeg-libs` from `rpmfusion-free` and `ffmpeg-libs` from `rpmfusion-free-updates`.
Here's a recent output of `sudo dnf update`:

```
opr repo for rendezvous owned by peterwu       1.2 kB/s | 1.8 kB     00:01    
Copr repo for PyCharm owned by phracek          1.0 kB/s | 2.1 kB     00:02    
Fedora 37 - x86_64                              5.2 kB/s | 5.6 kB     00:01    
Fedora 37 openh264 (From Cisco) - x86_64        1.1 kB/s | 989  B     00:00    
Fedora Modular 37 - x86_64                      5.6 kB/s | 5.5 kB     00:00    
Fedora 37 - x86_64 - Updates                    2.2 kB/s | 6.3 kB     00:02    
Fedora 37 - x86_64 - Updates                    309 kB/s | 3.1 MB     00:10    
Fedora Modular 37 - x86_64 - Updates            4.7 kB/s | 5.4 kB     00:01    
google-chrome                                   3.6 kB/s | 1.3 kB     00:00    
google-chrome                                   5.5 kB/s | 3.6 kB     00:00    
MEGAsync                                        2.1 kB/s | 1.5 kB     00:00    
Node.js Packages for Fedora Linux 37 - x86_64   1.0 kB/s | 2.5 kB     00:02    
RPM Fusion for Fedora 37 - Free                 7.1 kB/s |  11 kB     00:01    
RPM Fusion for Fedora 37 - Free - Updates        15 kB/s | 9.8 kB     00:00    
RPM Fusion for Fedora 37 - Nonfree               15 kB/s |  16 kB     00:01    
RPM Fusion for Fedora 37 - Nonfree - NVIDIA Dri 1.7 kB/s |  14 kB     00:08    
RPM Fusion for Fedora 37 - Nonfree - Steam       12 kB/s |  14 kB     00:01    
RPM Fusion for Fedora 37 - Nonfree - Updates     12 kB/s |  14 kB     00:01    
Dependencies resolved.

 Problem: package megasync-4.9.1.0-1.fc37.x86_64 requires ffmpeg-libs(x86-64), but none of the providers can be installed
  - package ffmpeg-libs-5.1.2-3.fc37.x86_64 conflicts with libavcodec-free provided by libavcodec-free-5.1.3-1.fc37.x86_64
  - package ffmpeg-libs-5.1.3-3.fc37.x86_64 conflicts with libavcodec-free provided by libavcodec-free-5.1.3-1.fc37.x86_64
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package megasync-4.9.1-3.1.x86_64
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package libavcodec-free-5.1.3-1.fc37.x86_64
================================================================================
 Package               Arch   Version           Repository                 Size
================================================================================
Upgrading:
 alsa-sof-firmware     noarch 2.2.5-1.fc37      updates                   3.4 M
 ansible-srpm-macros   noarch 1-10.fc37         updates                    20 k
 ethtool               x86_64 2:6.3-1.fc37      updates                   238 k
 firefox               x86_64 113.0.1-1.fc37    updates                    67 M
 firefox-langpacks     x86_64 113.0.1-1.fc37    updates                    43 M
 gnome-autoar          x86_64 0.4.4-1.fc37      updates                    59 k
 grilo                 x86_64 0.3.16-1.fc37     updates                   245 k
 perl-AutoLoader       noarch 5.74-494.fc37     updates                    22 k
 perl-B                x86_64 1.83-494.fc37     updates                   182 k
 perl-Class-Struct     noarch 0.66-494.fc37     updates                    23 k
 perl-DynaLoader       x86_64 1.52-494.fc37     updates                    27 k
 perl-Errno            x86_64 1.36-494.fc37     updates                    16 k
 perl-Fcntl            x86_64 1.15-494.fc37     updates                    21 k
 perl-File-Basename    noarch 2.85-494.fc37     updates                    18 k
 perl-File-Find        noarch 1.40-494.fc37     updates                    26 k
 perl-File-stat        noarch 1.12-494.fc37     updates                    18 k
 perl-FileHandle       noarch 2.03-494.fc37     updates                    16 k
 perl-Getopt-Std       noarch 1.13-494.fc37     updates                    17 k
 perl-IO               x86_64 1.50-494.fc37     updates                    93 k
 perl-IPC-Open3        noarch 1.22-494.fc37     updates                    24 k
 perl-NDBM_File        x86_64 1.15-494.fc37     updates                    23 k
 perl-POSIX            x86_64 2.03-494.fc37     updates                    98 k
 perl-SelectSaver      noarch 1.02-494.fc37     updates                    13 k
 perl-Symbol           noarch 1.09-494.fc37     updates                    15 k
 perl-base             noarch 2.27-494.fc37     updates                    17 k
 perl-if               noarch 0.61.000-494.fc37 updates                    15 k
 perl-interpreter      x86_64 4:5.36.1-494.fc37 updates                    73 k
 perl-lib              x86_64 0.65-494.fc37     updates                    16 k
 perl-libs             x86_64 4:5.36.1-494.fc37 updates                   2.2 M
 perl-mro              x86_64 1.26-494.fc37     updates                    30 k
 perl-overload         noarch 1.35-494.fc37     updates                    47 k
 perl-overloading      noarch 0.02-494.fc37     updates                    14 k
 perl-subs             noarch 1.04-494.fc37     updates                    13 k
 perl-vars             noarch 1.05-494.fc37     updates                    14 k
 pyproject-srpm-macros noarch 1.8.0-1.fc37      updates                    15 k
Installing dependencies:
 perl-locale           noarch 1.10-494.fc37     updates                    15 k
Skipping packages with conflicts:
(add '--best --allowerasing' to command line to force their upgrade):
 ffmpeg-libs           x86_64 5.1.2-3.fc37      rpmfusion-free            7.9 M
 ffmpeg-libs           x86_64 5.1.3-3.fc37      rpmfusion-free-updates    7.9 M
Skipping packages with broken dependencies:
 megasync              x86_64 4.9.1.0-1.fc37    rpmfusion-nonfree-updates 9.6 M

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install   1 Package
Upgrade  35 Packages
Skip      3 Packages

Total download size: 117 M
Is this ok [y/N]:
```

Also, I ran `sudo dnf upgrade --refresh --best --allowerasing` but that didn't work either:

```
opr repo for rendezvous owned by peterwu       1.4 kB/s | 1.8 kB     00:01    
Copr repo for PyCharm owned by phracek          1.1 kB/s | 2.1 kB     00:01    
Fedora 37 - x86_64                              5.3 kB/s | 5.6 kB     00:01    
Fedora 37 openh264 (From Cisco) - x86_64        918  B/s | 989  B     00:01    
Fedora Modular 37 - x86_64                      5.9 kB/s | 5.5 kB     00:00    
Fedora 37 - x86_64 - Updates                    6.2 kB/s | 6.3 kB     00:01    
Fedora Modular 37 - x86_64 - Updates            6.0 kB/s | 5.4 kB     00:00    
google-chrome                                   3.1 kB/s | 1.3 kB     00:00    
MEGAsync                                        1.9 kB/s | 1.5 kB     00:00    
Node.js Packages for Fedora Linux 37 - x86_64   1.3 kB/s | 2.5 kB     00:01    
RPM Fusion for Fedora 37 - Free                  11 kB/s |  11 kB     00:01    
RPM Fusion for Fedora 37 - Free - Updates       8.4 kB/s | 9.8 kB     00:01    
RPM Fusion for Fedora 37 - Nonfree               23 kB/s |  16 kB     00:00    
RPM Fusion for Fedora 37 - Nonfree - NVIDIA Dri  13 kB/s |  14 kB     00:01    
RPM Fusion for Fedora 37 - Nonfree - Steam       12 kB/s |  14 kB     00:01    
RPM Fusion for Fedora 37 - Nonfree - Updates     21 kB/s |  14 kB     00:00    
Error: 
 Problem: cannot install the best update candidate for package libavcodec-free-5.1.3-1.fc37.x86_64
  - problem with installed package libavcodec-free-5.1.3-1.fc37.x86_64
  - package megasync-4.9.1.0-1.fc37.x86_64 requires ffmpeg-libs(x86-64), but none of the providers can be installed
  - package ffmpeg-libs-5.1.2-3.fc37.x86_64 conflicts with libavcodec-free provided by libavcodec-free-5.1.3-1.fc37.x86_64
  - package ffmpeg-libs-5.1.3-3.fc37.x86_64 conflicts with libavcodec-free provided by libavcodec-free-5.1.3-1.fc37.x86_64
  - problem with installed package megasync-4.9.1-3.1.x86_64
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package megasync-4.9.1-3.1.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)
```

How do I resolve the issue? I'd like to upgrade to Fedora 38, but I guess there'd be problems due to the conflicts, and the resulting broken dependencies.

PS: I've tried removing `libavcodec-free`, but I couldn't because `ffmpeg-free`, `gnome-shell-extension-gsconnect` and others are dependent on it. Also, if I know right, `libavcodec` is an important video and audio encoding tool used by VLC and others.

Comment: You might want to investigate rpmfusion's [FFmpeg-free Complement](https://rpmfusion.org/CommonBugs#FFmpeg-free_Complement).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [RPM Fusion — CommonBugs FFmpeg-free Complement](https://rpmfusion.org/CommonBugs#FFmpeg-free_Complement):

> - Status: Fixed (to some extend)
> - Bug: https://github.com/rpmfusion/ffmpeg/pull/3
>
> With the introduction of FFmpeg in Fedora, we had an initial solution to conflict with this lame version. But this isn't ideal as most users using graphical interface won't be able to use full featured version. As with Fedora 37, we are building a complement package (libavcodec-freeworld) that can be installed along the ffmpeg-free libraries.
>
> [image] Note: It is still recommended to switch to the full featured ffmpeg version from RPM Fusion to avoid weird interaction issue:
>
> ```
> sudo dnf swap ffmpeg-free ffmpeg --allowerasing
> ```